# Error deleting old files with Log4j2

Tags: log4j2

I need to delete old logs files that rolls daily. To limit the number of files I've tried:

```
    <RollingFile 
        name="FileAppender" 
        fileName="${baseDir}/mylog.log" 
        filePattern="${baseDir}/mylog %d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip">
         <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} [%p] %c{1} - %m%n"/>
         <Policies>              
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />            
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5">        
    </RollingFile>
```

But the logs are not deleted.

Now I'm triying

```
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="0">                 
            <IfLastModified age="5d" />
        </Delete>
    </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
```

But I get the error:

**ERROR DefaultRolloverStrategy contains an invalid element or attribute "Delete"**

There is something wrong with my log4j2.xml file?

I use maven with:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade your version of Log4j. The Delete feature was introduced in 2.5. The latest version now is 2.7. I recommend using the latest.

Also check the documentation for the maxDepth attribute. You should probably specify 1 or more. Zero means the directory itself, not the files in that dir.

Comment: Thanks the Delete element is now accepted, but log4j2 still doesn't delete the files. I define <If LastModified age="3d" /> but although I change my computer's system date the log files remain.

Comment: @MarcoA.Hernandez have you resolved this? Im doing testing to change my computer system date also...